# Taking identical 1st element of a list and assigning it as 1st element of the list in python

Tags: python

I am trying to Taking identical 1st element of  a list and assigning it as 1st element of the list. I was told it can be done by using defaultdict from collections module but is there a way i can do this without using the Collections library.

What i have:

```
mapping = [['Tom', 'BTPS 1.500 625', 0.702604], ['Tom', 'BTPS 2.000 1225', 0.724939], ['Max', 'OBL 0.0 421', 0.766102], ['Max', 'DBR 3.250 721', 0.887863]]
```

What i am looking to do:

```
mapping = [['Tom',[ 'BTPS 1.500 625', 0.702604], [ 'BTPS 2.000 1225', 0.724939]],['Max',[ 'OBL 0.0 421', 0.766102],['DBR 3.250 721', 0.887863]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a *dict*/[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the data by name, using the first element which is the key as the name, slicing the rest of the data and appending that as a value:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for sub in mapping:
     d[sub[0]].append(sub[1:])

print(d)
```

Which would give you:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Max': [['OBL 0.0 421', 0.766102], ['DBR 3.250 721', 0.887863]], 'Tom': [['BTPS 1.500 625', 0.702604], ['BTPS 2.000 1225', 0.724939]]})
```

Or if the order matters, use an [*OrderedDict*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for sub in mapping:
     d.setdefault(sub[0],[]).append(sub[1:])
```

That gives you:

```
OrderedDict([('Tom', [['BTPS 1.500 625', 0.702604], ['BTPS 2.000 1225', 0.724939]]), ('Max', [['OBL 0.0 421', 0.766102], ['DBR 3.250 721', 0.887863]])])
```

Without any imports, just use a regular dict again using [dict.setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm):

```
d = {}
for sub in mapping:
     d.setdefault(sub[0],[]).append(sub[1:])

print(d)
```

Using  setdefault, if the key is not in the dict it gets added with a list as the value, if it does exist it just appends the value.

Comment: Thanks Padraic for such a quick response. Is it possible without having to import the collection module?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the names in mapping and add to dictionary.

```
mapping = [['Tom', 'BTPS 1.500 625', 0.702604], ['Tom', 'BTPS 2.000 1225', 0.724939], ['Max', 'OBL 0.0 421', 0.766102], ['Max', 'DBR 3.250 721', 0.887863]]

#using dictionary to store output
mapping_dict=dict()

for items in mapping:
if items[0] in mapping_dict:
    mapping_dict[items[0]].append([items[1],items[2]])
else:
    mapping_dict[items[0]]=[items[1],items[2]]

print mapping_dict

Output: {'Max': ['OBL 0.0 421', 0.766102, ['DBR 3.250 721', 0.887863]], 'Tom': ['BTPS 1.500 625', 0.702604, ['BTPS 2.000 1225', 0.724939]]}
```